# Embedding Google Analytics Dashboards into Custom Website

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have recently implemented Google Analytics on my website and have been exploring the various features and dashboards available on analytics.google.com. I find these dashboards to be quite useful in analyzing website traffic and user behavior.

Now, I would like to take it a step further and embed these Google Analytics dashboards into my own custom website, which is hosted at mycompany.com.au. By doing so, I aim to provide a seamless experience for my website visitors, allowing them to access the analytics data without leaving my website.

I have searched through the Google Analytics documentation and online resources, but I haven't found a clear guideline on how to achieve this. I am aware of the Google Analytics API and the availability of embedding options for other Google products like Google Maps. However, I am uncertain if similar embedding capabilities exist for Google Analytics dashboards.

My ultimate goal is to have a dedicated page on mycompany.com.au where users can view the Google Analytics dashboards specific to my website's performance. This would enable me to present the analytics data within the context of my own branding and website design.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, guidance, or resources that can help me achieve this goal. If embedding Google Analytics dashboards into a custom website is possible, I would like to know the recommended approach, any prerequisites, and the necessary steps to implement it successfully.

Thank you in advance for your assistance and expertise.

Comment: I  was able to embed dashboards into my site via Google Looker ( Free BI tool from google ), (i) Enable Google Looker to grab data from  Google Analytics, (ii) design visualisation on Google Looker, and  (iii) embed into my site.

Answer (score 2):

You cant directly.

What you can do is use the Google analytics embedded api to which will allow you to show a users google analytics accounts nicely, but your going to have to design all the requests yourself to mirror the Google analytics reports, this also only works with UA analytics not GA4

Byond that you could use the Google analytics api, to request the data yourself and use google charts and graphs to display it nicely on your website.

I guess what I am saying there is nothing out of the box that will do this for you Its something your going to have to code yourself.  I have done it for serval clients it can be done very elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think google allows you to have an iframe on their analytics page, but you can set up events to go to Big Query, then access Big Query to create your own sites

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can create your analytics dashboards on Google looker studio and embed it to your website.

Comment: You answer needs a little more effort to be helpful.  A top notch answer would provide the instructions for A)creating the dashboard, and B) embedding it in a webpage.  It could still be very helpful if you provided a clue about the source of your belief, like "Try searching for 'embed' in the documentation at ...", or do that yourself and explain what you find that is related to embedding analytics dashboards.